# What is important in a job description?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I am applying for a masters programme in Computer Science in the UK.
In the application I am asked to provide a description of any jobs I had so far.

What is important in such a job description, i.e. what information should I include? 
How long should it be?

There is an html form with a text field but the maximum length is unspecified.

Comment: Is this for a CV/fill-in-the-blank? A text-field? If possible, provide us info on how much we can write. A 100 character textbox vs. 1000 will allow for much different levels of detail.

Comment: just edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was on a graduate committee, I would want to know

- How long you held the job.
- What your responsibilities were: e.g. if I was an aide in an undergrad class, did I grade homework? Did I teach the class sometimes? Did I have contact with students? Did I write tests?
- How did this job prepare you for admittance into the graduate program. What relevant skills did you obtain?
- If the person that oversaw you in the said job is known to the application committee, perhaps say who you worked for. Or if it is a company, say who the company is. There is a huge difference between "Software Engineer" at a company with 5000 employees and "Software Engineer" at a start-up in someone's basement.

Comment: there are 3 jobs i deem relevant: first as a penetration tester, second as a software developer (bachelor thesis) and third as an aide in an undergrad class

Comment: These all sound relevant to me. Good luck.